# Javascript indexOf not return exact value, any solution?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, indexof

Please, how to add multiple queries and return only the exact value?

```
    if( placeholder.indexOf('Document') != -1 ){
        $(this).addClass('cpf');
    }
    if( placeholder.indexOf("Document B") != -1 ){
        $(this).addClass('cnpj');
    }
    if( placeholder.indexOf("Document A and B") != -1 ){
        $(this).addClass('cpf_cnpj');
    }
```

If my placeholder is "Document A and B", return only the class "cpf_cnpj" and not all classes.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please include the relevant HTML.

Comment: <input size="1" type="text" name="form_fields[field_1]" id="form-field-field_1" class="elementor-field elementor-size-sm  elementor-field-textual" placeholder="Document A and B" maxlength="18">

Comment: `if() else if()....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `else...if`. Also you do not need `indexOf()` at all, you can directly check the *placeholder* value with strictly equality operator (`===`) or equality operator (`==`).

**Demo:**

```js
$('input').on('focus', function(){
  var placeholder = $(this).attr('placeholder');
  if( placeholder == 'Document'){
    $(this).addClass('cpf');
  }
  else if( placeholder == 'Document B'){
    $(this).addClass('cnpj');
  }
  else if( placeholder == 'Document A and B'){
    $(this).addClass('cpf_cnpj');
  }
});
```

```css
input{
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.cpf { border: 2px solid red }
.cnpj { border: 2px solid green }
.cpf_cnpj { border: 2px solid blue }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input size="1" type="text" name="form_fields[field_1]" id="form-field-field_1" class="elementor-field elementor-size-sm elementor-field-textual" placeholder="Document" maxlength="18">

<input size="1" type="text" name="form_fields[field_1]" id="form-field-field_1" class="elementor-field elementor-size-sm elementor-field-textual" placeholder="Document B" maxlength="18">

<input size="1" type="text" name="form_fields[field_1]" id="form-field-field_1" class="elementor-field elementor-size-sm elementor-field-textual" placeholder="Document A and B" maxlength="18">
```

Though I will prefer using ***data-**** attribute which does not require the checking at all:

```js
$('input').on('focus', function(){
  var el_class = $(this).data('class');
  $(this).addClass(el_class);
});
```

```css
input{
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.cpf { border: 2px solid red }
.cnpj { border: 2px solid green }
.cpf_cnpj { border: 2px solid blue }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input size="1" type="text" name="form_fields[field_1]" id="form-field-field_1" class="elementor-field elementor-size-sm elementor-field-textual" placeholder="Document" maxlength="18" data-class="cpf">

<input size="1" type="text" name="form_fields[field_1]" id="form-field-field_1" class="elementor-field elementor-size-sm elementor-field-textual" placeholder="Document B" maxlength="18" data-class="cnpj">

<input size="1" type="text" name="form_fields[field_1]" id="form-field-field_1" class="elementor-field elementor-size-sm elementor-field-textual" placeholder="Document A and B" maxlength="18" data-class="cpf_cnpj">
```

Comment: Thank you very much for u support! =)

Comment: @RodrigoBogdanowicz, you are most welcome:)

Answer (score 1):

So start with most specific with if/else if

```
if (placeholder === 'Document A and B') {
  $(this).addClass('cpf_cnpj');
} else if (placeholder.indexOf("Document B") != -1) {
  $(this).addClass('cnpj');
} else { // or else if( placeholder.indexOf('Document') != -1 ){
  $(this).addClass('cpf');
}
```